# How should I visualise uncertainty in a histogram from survey sampling?

Tags: r, data-visualization, histogram, weights, ggplot2

I have a numeric variable $\{x_i\}$, which corresponding weights $\{w_i\}$, where the weights are survey weights from a corresponding complex survey design.

**I want to visualise a weighted histogram of $\{x_i\}$ that also communicates the uncertainty on $\{x_i\}$ due to sampling error. What are some good ways to communicate this uncertainty?** (I know how to make the weighted histogram, it's the uncertainty that I would like assistance with). If code answers are supplied, in R would be preferable.

Note 1: In the past, I have created a histogram with error intervals (standard error) on the height of each histogram bar. But that seems clunky to me, and I was hoping to find out about other statistical visualisation techniques.

Note 2: For the sake of making visualisation examples, feel free to just make up uncertainties/errors. I will calculate them in my own project using jack-knife replicate weights.

Comment: Is $x_i$ continuous, categorical, or both?

Comment: It's a numeric variable. In my particular use case, it's a non-negative integer (but that's probably not relevant for answering the question). Thanks, I have clarified that in the question body.

Comment: Is this generally a 5 point scale or 10 point scale, or does it range over 100s of integers?  The reason I am trying to pin this down is that it really affects the type of visualization I would recommend.

Comment: There are a huge number of possibilities depending on your audience.  John Tukey proposed the [Rootogram](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/424979/919) for similar purposes (with sophisticated audiences). One advantage it has is that every bar has (to a good approximation) the *same* uncertainty, eliminating the issue of how to visually represent varying degrees of uncertainty.  Depending on the details, you might be able to adapt this approach.

Comment: @RCarnell it's just count/integer variables. Potentially they could all be less than 10. Potentially they could be in the 100s. It's going to be presented as a histogram though, so I would think it's more the bins that matter than the magnitude of the counts.

Comment: @whuber thank you for your suggestion - I'll keep that in mind for future applications.