# VST for negative binomial random variable

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution, variance-stabilizing

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance-stabilizing_transformation

The variance stabilizing transform of a Poisson random variable is the Anscombe transform. What is the VST for a negative binomial random variable?

Comment: Re "The:" a variance stabilizing transform is not unique.  For instance, the square root is another variance-stabilizing transform of the Poisson family.  A general method for finding a variance-stabilizing transform is given at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/251449.

Comment: I am looking for the best vst.

Comment: "Best" in what sense?

Comment: In the sense that the Anscombe transform is better than the sqrt transform for Poison distribution.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at Anscombe's paper from 1948 [the transformation of Poisson, Binomial and Negative-Binomial data](https://doi.org/10.2307/2332343). There, he shows that for a random variable
$$
Y \sim \text{NegBin}(m, k),
$$
where $m$ is the mean and $k$ is the size, the transformation
$$
Z = \sinh^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{Y + c}{k - 2c}}
$$
with $c \approx 3/8$ is in some sense optimal.